# Write csv file (including header) via dataset

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I want to create a function that takes a file name and a dataset, and in turn, creates a .csv file with the dictionary keys as a header and the values in the rows beneath the header. I would like this to be independent of the number of columns in the dataset. Also, if any of the columns shows no data I still want the rest of the data to be written in the .csv file.

My current code looks like this:

```
def write_data_to_csv(csv_name, dataset):
import csv 

with open(f"{csv_name}.csv", "w") as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter = ";")
    writer.writerow(["iso_country", "continent", "country", "population", "population_density", "date", "total_cases"])
    for i in dataset:
        try:
            writer.writerow([i['iso_country'], i['continent'], i['date'], i['total_cases']])
        except:
            0
```

My data looks like this:

```
[{'iso_country': 'ALB',
  'continent': 'Europe',
  'location': 'Albania',
  'population': 2877800.0,
  'population_density': 104.871,
  'date': '2021-03-05',
  'total_cases': 111301.0},
 {'iso_country': 'ALB',
  'continent': 'Europe',
  'location': 'Albania',
  'population': 2877800.0,
  'population_density': 104.871,
  'date': '2021-03-05',
  'total_cases': 111301.0}]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Jelle What is the error you are facing right now?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this simple `write_csv()` function to write any list of dicts to a csv:

```py
import csv
from typing import List, Dict

def write_csv(data: List[Dict], path: str) -> None:
    with open(path, 'w', newline='') as file:
        fields = set().union(*data)
        writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=fields)
        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerows(data)

csv_data = [{'iso_country': 'ALB',
             'continent': 'Europe',
             'location': 'Albania',
             'population': 2877800.0,
             'population_density': 104.871,
             'date': '2021-03-05',
             'total_cases': 111301.0},
            {'iso_country': 'ALB',
             'continent': 'Europe',
             'location': 'Albania',
             'population': 2877800.0,
             'population_density': 104.871,
             'date': '2021-03-05',
             'total_cases': 111301.0}]

write_csv(csv_data, 'data.csv')
```

The `typing` import is just to make the documentation automatic for most IDEs

Comment: Good answer. While the way the detection of the columns is done is fairly clever IMO, it should at least be noted that the use of a `set` to do so isn't going to preserve their order—although it may not matter. You should also add a `newline=""` to the file `open()` call (as the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-csv) directs. In addition  I would also suggest *not* specifying the line terminator and using the module's default value. On my computer it still ends them with `'\r\n'` (because of the lack of `newline=""`).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! The line terminator is for windows but i guess `newline=""` is a better way to do it. I generally equate dictionaries with json anyways which is unordered by standard (unless using an ordereddict?) so for humans the order may matter but for data, nah.

Comment: Now it's even better `;¬)`. Since the output file has a header row, the order of the fields probably doesn't matter. FWIW, the [RFC 4180](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180.html) CSV file format standard specifies that "Each record is located on a separate line, delimited by a line break (CRLF)" (regardless of the OS involved). I think that's what Excel running on the MacOS does.